# What does the Quran mean by punishment in Al-Baqarah?

Tags: quran, punishment, surat-al-baqarah, verses

It says in a verse:

> As to those who reject Faith, it is the same to them whether thou warn them or do not warn them; they will not believe. Allah has set a seal upon their hearts and upon their hearing, and over their vision is a veil. And for them is a great punishment.
>
> [Source](http://quran.com/2).

What I understand is that the non-believers get a punishment. What do they mean with punishment? Is it related to jihad?

Sorry if I have a misunderstanding!

Comment: Also there is a hugh different between non believers and koffar (kafir) as that verse says inna alladhina kafaro... Look up the definition of kafir.

Comment: @kilise the difference is just that disbeliever see and understand islam and say "no". anyone who is not muslim, but is not aware of islam is not a disbeliever but just a non muslim right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tanwîr al-Miqbâs min Tafsîr Ibn ‘Abbâs gives the following commentary:

> (Allah hath sealed their hearts), stamped their hearts, (and their hearing, and on their eyes there is a covering), on their eyes there is a shield (and theirs will be an awful doom) an awful torment in the **Hereafter**.

Al-Jalalayn gives the commentary:

> for them there will be a mighty chastisement, that is, intense and **everlasting**.

Clearly, the punishment mentioned in the verse refers to the punishment of the Hereafter. It has no connotation of Jihad.

And only Allah knows the appropriate punishment for each individual.

Answer (score 1):

When Punishemnt is mentionned in Quran, it means (most of time) punishment after death : Hell : *Djahanem*.

Jihad is not a punishemnt, and there's no notion of punishment related to jihad.

Answer (score 0):

Only Allah can punish anyone for not accepting Islam as faith. Its not the job of a person.

"So render good counsel, for you are simply required to counsel, and are not invested with the authority to compel them.  But whoever will turn away , Allah will chastise him with the most terrible chastisement." Quran 88:21-24

"Had your Lord so willed, all those who are on the earth would have believed. Will you, then, force people into believing?" Quran 10:99

"There is no compulsion and coercion in regard to religion. The right thing has been made distinct from the wrong thing: now whoever rejects taghut and believes in Allah has taken a firm support that never gives way." Quran 2:256

One may keep in mind that Allah is just and says that no one will be wronged on the day of judgement.

"And We do not lay on any soul a burden except to the extent of its ability, and with Us is a book which speaks the truth, and they shall not be dealt with unjustly." Quran 23:62